# python: convert parenthesis to bracket

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to check if longitude, latitude is in polygon in Python 3. The code below works, but I have a problem putting data from variable.

```
lng_lat = Point(42.01410106690003, 20.97770690917969)

#this is how I need to add data
polygon = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
print(lng_lat.within(poly))
```

but my data are like this (I get data from json file with json.load)

```
coordinate[0]=[[20.94320297241211, 41.99777372492389], [20.923118591308594, 41.98578066472604] , [20.917625427246094, 41.970467091533], [20.936164855957028, 41.94825586972943]]
```

How can I pass data from **coordinates[0]** to **polygon** which requires **( )** instead of **[ ]**

and this doesn't work

```
polygon = Polygon(coordinates[0])
```

Comment: Why do you think that `Polygon(coordinates[0])` doesn't work?

Comment: Post the specific result of what you tried. "Didn't work" is not specific enough.

Comment: What is `Point` and what is `Poligon`? i.e. where they come from, what package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear whether they need to be tuples or Point instances...

Also your print statement is trying to print `poly` which doesn't exist in the code you included.

```
lng_lat = Point(42.01410106690003, 20.97770690917969)

coordinate[0]=[[20.94320297241211, 41.99777372492389], [20.923118591308594, 41.98578066472604] , [20.917625427246094, 41.970467091533], [20.936164855957028, 41.94825586972943]]
```

If tuples then:

```
data = [tuple(i) for i in coorinate[0]]
polygon = Polygon(data)
print(lng_lat.within(polygon))
```

and if they need to be Point Instances:

```
data = [Point(i) for i in coorinate[0]]
polygon = Polygon(data)
print(lng_lat.within(polygon))
```

Comment: tuples is correct